# Column-family database sharding and replication [NoSQL Distilled]

Tags: nosql, cassandra, replication, sharding, bigtable

In section *4.5 Combining Sharding and Replication* of the NoSQL Distilled book, the following assertion is made:

> "Using peer-to-peer replication and sharding is a common strategy for column-family databases."

The statement leaves out other types of cluster-ready databases, namely key-value and document stores. Why is this the case? Are those databases well suited for sharding, but not in conjunction with peer-to-peer replication? Is master-slave replication a better approach in those cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peer-to-peer replication has more to do with the consistency model.  You're making a tradeoff between fault tolerance and consistency, where a peer-to-peer model chooses the former and a master-slave model the latter.  It is possible to achieve consistency through means such as using quorum reads and writes, so you can often achieve both in practice--even though the database isn't technically consistent.

There are certainly examples of non-CF stores that use peer-to-peer replication, such as [CouchBase](http://www.couchbase.com/), a document store, and [Riak](http://wiki.basho.com/), a KV store.  These databases perform very well and use auto-sharding in some form.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the main issue is the consistency model: write-write conflicts, in the case of peer-to-peer replication, vs. eventual consistency with master-slave replication. However, I don't find any reason for the authors to highlight column-family databases, and your mentioning of Riak and CouchBase seems to back my reasoning :)